# Hide HTML5 number input’s spin box but accepts alphanumeric characters

Tags: css, html, jquery-mobile

i have hidden the spinbox arrows from an input type="number" but the number restrictions doesn't work already. Hence, the numberbox now accepts alphanumeric characters.

I used this code when i was able to hide the spinner arrows:

```
input::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
input::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
    /* display: none; <- Crashes Chrome on hover */
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    margin: 0; /* <-- Apparently some margin are still there even though it's hidden */
}
```

hi @BenM! thanks for editing my question. Now, thanks for the idea of using *javascript* @FakeRainBrigand but it didn't work for me.

This worked for me though. I'm using **MVC** and **Razor**

`
        function keeypress(e) {
        var unicode = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.charCode

```
    if (unicode == 8) {
            return;
        };

    if (unicode == 37 || unicode == 39 || unicode == 38 || unicode == 40 || unicode == 27) {
        return;
        }
        else {

        };

    if (unicode == 13) {
            e.preventDefault();
        };

    if ($.isNumeric(String.fromCharCode(unicode)) == false) {
            e.preventDefault();
        };
    }
```

`

Comment: I used the **Razor** in the **MVC** _masterpage_ `@RenderSection("NumValidation", required: false)`

Comment: and I put these codelets on the element of input:

onkeypress="keeypress(event)" onchange="keeypress(event)"

Answer (score 0):

You need to use client side script like JavaScript. It's better to [use jquery validation](http://www.javascript-coder.com/html-form/javascript-form-validation.phtml) to restrict alphanumeric character from the form inputs.

Comment: Usually I'd agree with you, but this answer also specifies the *what*.